# Is there a way to calculate the standard deviation of a given range in excel, based on a cell entry in another column?

Tags: excel

I am trying to use a specific entry in excel that will find all matches in a column and calculate the standard deviation of the range for data in another column that match.  Let's say I have the entry in cell K3 called Day of Interest. In K4 I have the data I want to be found in this case "D0".  In a given set of data I want to match all entries in one column that have "D0" and calculate the standard deviation of their concentrations from another column.  If you look at column 2 the issue I'm running into is I cannot figure out how to have the formula look for a range of values given my entry.  I want the cell I input D0 into to be found in another table and the stddev to be calculated.  I am not sure how to generate the range in the formula.

Table1

| Day | Concentration |
| --- | --- |
| D0 | 22 |
| D0 | 40 |
| D7 | 50 |
| D7 | 25 |
| D8 | 35 |
| D9 | 50 |

Below is what I have tried in excel.

Table 2

| Day of Interest | Standard Deviation |
| --- | --- |
| D0 | =If(K3="","",(stddev.p('insert a range here based on K3' |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FILTER function helps here.

The formula is `=IF(K3="","",STDEV.P(FILTER(Table1[Concentration],Table1[Day]=K3)))`

FILTER creates an array based on a condition being true.

Comment: Do I need to ctrl+shft+enter when using this formula with filter?

Comment: This worked as stated.  I just needed to turn my data into a table first.  Thanks!